# Implementing a non-public assignment operator with a public named method?

Tags: c++, clone, assignment-operator

<strike>It is supposed to copy an AnimatedSprite. I'm having second thoughts that it has the unfortunate side effect of changing the *this object.</strike>

How would I implement this feature without the side effect?

EDIT:

Based on new answers, the question should really be: How do I implement a non-public assignment operator with a public named method <strike>without side effects</strike>? (Changed title as such).

```
public:
AnimatedSprite& AnimatedSprite::Clone(const AnimatedSprite& animatedSprite) {
    return (*this = animatedSprite);
}

protected:
AnimatedSprite& AnimatedSprite::operator=(const AnimatedSprite& rhs) {
    if(this == &rhs) return *this;

    destroy_bitmap(this->_frameImage);
    this->_frameImage = create_bitmap(rhs._frameImage->w, rhs._frameImage->h);
    clear_bitmap(this->_frameImage);
    this->_frameDimensions = rhs._frameDimensions;
    this->CalcCenterFrame();
    this->_frameRate = rhs._frameRate;
    if(rhs._animation != nullptr) {
        delete this->_animation;
        this->_animation = new a2de::AnimationHandler(*rhs._animation);
    } else {
        delete this->_animation;
        this->_animation = nullptr;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you inadvertently confused the issue by picking the name `clone` - like `swap` pre-C++11, it has a specific meaning in idiomatic C++.

Comment: There's no getting around changing `this`, because an assignment changes it by definition. You can call the private assignment operator from your method, as per my updated answer.

Comment: @JoeGauterin What do you suggest I rename the method to?

Comment: @Casey I'm not sure - I still don't know what you're hoping to achieve. Why do you want to implement your assignment operator in that way? Why don't you want the method to have side effects (assignment is a mutating operation - it's nothing but side effect)?

Comment: @JoeGauterin Fixed question. Old text was still lingering. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the private assignment operator:

```
public:
AnimatedSprite& AnimatedSprite::Clone(const AnimatedSprite& animatedSprite) {
    return ( operator=(animatedSprite));
}
```

There is no getting around modifying `this` if you are trying to do assignment

<strike>Typically, clone returns a pointer or smart pointer to a new instance:</strike>

```
struct IFoo {
  virtual IFoo* clone() const = 0;
};
struct Foo1 : public virtual IFoo {
  virtual IFoo* clone() { return new Foo1(this);}
};
struct Foo2 : public virtual IFoo {
  virtual IFoo* clone() { return new Foo2(this);}
};

IFoo* foo0 = new Foo1();
...
IFoo* fooClone = foo0.clone();
```

Comment: Also typically, as you show it in your code, Clone method do not have any parameters and just return copy of itself

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone should not have parameters, cause it should clone itself. If you want to change *this you have operator =.
2. Try to return value. If you create temp object in return, than it could be optimized by compiler to construct new object without having temp.

   AnimatedSprite AnimatedSprite::Clone() {
       return AnimatedSprite(*this);
   }

   AnimatedSprite clone = someObject.Clone(); // will not lead to creating temp object

// edited

So you need something like this? Also I'm not sure, why you need reference returned.

```
public:
AnimatedSprite& AnimatedSprite::CopyTo(AnimatedSprite& animatedSprite) {
    animatedSprite = *this;
    return *this;
}

AnimatedSprite& AnimatedSprite::CopyFrom(AnimatedSprite& animatedSprite) {
    return (*this = animatedSprite);
}
```